# Rails ActiveRecord only return distinct records based on a column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have an ActiveRecord model called Checkin and I only want to return Checkin records distinct by the user_id. Is there way to do this that returns an AR relation? I need to apply multiple scopes to it so I would prefer to avoid find_by_sql.

Example:

Let's say we have the following records

```
id: 1
user_id : 5
location_id: 12

id: 2
user_id: 25
location_id: 12

id: 3
user_id: 5
location_id: 12
```

I want to be able to say something like:
Checkin.distinct_by(:user_id) and have that return only rows 1 and 2 (because user_id=5 should be distinct). I would like this to be an ActiveRecord:Relation ideally so that I can apply other conditions onto this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your question more clear, can you provide some example? I don't know this is what you are looking for: you can try to use "select" or "collect" function after your where statement.